# https: Apache TLS renegotiation: Debian, Apache2, openssl. How to?

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

On modern browsers, my site gets marked as sorta insecure:

Google Chrome for example says "**`The server does not support the TLS renegotiation extension`**" in the "Page Information".

HTTPS runs fine though, the connection is encrypted and the certificate is valid.

```
# openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007

# cat /etc/debian_version
5.0.6

# apache2ctl -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.9 (Debian)
Server built:   Apr 20 2010 21:44:40
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:15
Server loaded:  APR 1.2.12, APR-Util 1.2.12
Compiled using: APR 1.2.12, APR-Util 1.2.12
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     ITK
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/experimental/itk"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT=""
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="/var/run/apache2/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/apache2/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/apache2/apache2.conf"
```

I'm using the dotdeb repository for my LAMP setup, hence Apache 2.2.9.

- Is there something wrong with my
  server configuration?
- Or is there something wrong with the
  certificate in use?
- Where should I begin tracking down
  the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Debian changelog](http://packages.debian.org/changelogs/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.2.9-10+lenny8/changelog), you're using the apache2 package version 2.2.9-10+lenny8 (the latest one available for Lenny), built Apr 20 2010.
Version 2.2.9-10+lenny6 had introduced a quick fix for the problem (CVE-2009-3555):

> Reject any client-initiated SSL/TLS
>   renegotiations. This is a partial fix
>          for the TLS renegotiation prefix injection attack
>   (CVE-2009-3555).
>          Any configuration which requires renegotiation for
>   per-directory/location
>          access control or uses "SSLVerifyClient optional" is still
>   vulnerable.

Therefore, you should disable `SSLVerifyClient optional` in `Directory` or `Location` directives.

The TLS renegotiation extension (RFC 5746), which addresses the problem in `SSLVerifyClient optional` more generally, was implemented in OpenSSL versions 0.9.8m and 1.0.0a, which you would need if you wanted to use it.

If you're not using `SSLVerifyClient optional` in location/directory directives, your configuration doesn't seem insecure, it just doesn't support this TLS extension that would have allowed you to keep using client-certificate authentication on a per-directory/location basis.

[Apache Httpd 2.2.15](http://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/CHANGES_2.2) also introduced the [`SSLInsecureRenegotiation`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslinsecurerenegotiation) directive if you want to force the insecure behaviour (and use OpenSSL 0.9.8m or above).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why but I stumbled into what appears to be a fix for this issue.  I had only 1 vhost for SSL and noticed a redirect from http -> https wasn't working.  I tried a number of variations of the rewrite rules to no avail.  So I decided to create a second vhost on port 80.  The redirect started working and not only that, Chrome started showing the green https symbol in the corner :D